# MVC 4 Razor and Jquery UI datepicker() "Object doesn't support property or method"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor, datepicker

I've probably just spent the last two hours trying to figure this out.

The specific error that is thrown with my MVC application is this:
"0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'"

Here is my code:

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<head>

...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
</head>
```

**the view .cshtml**

```
@{
    ...
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

...
<div>
    Change Time Span:
    <br />
    From:
    <input type="text" id="test" />
</div>

<div class="loading" id="container">@Model.LoadingMessage</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#test').datepicker();
    });

</script>
```

I've looked at several potential "duplicate" questions with no success. Here are some of the questions I've looked at:

[MVC3 razor view error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468102/mvc3-razor-view-error-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-pr)
[jQuery giving error "Object doesn't support this property or method" on method datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105194/jquery-giving-error-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-on-method-d)
[Using datepicker in MVC 4.0 to persist a date value in db, throwing "object doesn't support this property or method"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148765/using-datepicker-in-mvc-4-0-to-persist-a-date-value-in-db-throwing-object-does)

1. I believe I am referencing all that I need from jquery to accomplish my goal.
2. The  element is readable from Jquery, it can see its value were I to set it, so I don't think my selector is the problem.
3. Both Jquery Packages were installed via NuGet (the latest Jquery release and the Jquery UI Combined Library)
4. I've rebuilt / cleaned the Visual Studio solution (in desperation), shut down the local IIS host and reset it...

What am I missing? Intellisense even detects that the method exists and is giving me suggestions for what to place in for parameters.

**Is there something simple I've missed?**

Comment: Just to be sure, have you checked that the jquery ui path is correct? Can you check in chrome console for any 404 efrors?

Comment: Sure - Chrome Console comes back with: 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Comment: Hmm, just for giggles, can you replace your scripts with these from Google's CDN:  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Chris, thanks for the suggestion. This is one of the suggestions in another similar question - and I have definitely tried this to no avail. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Required scripts
----------------

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>



<p>Date:<input type="text" id="Dob" class="datefield" /></p>



<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Dob").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Marked this as answer, because the actual solution was to stop using JQuery2.0 with JQuery 1.10 - When I went down to JQuery 1.9 or 1.10 instead of Jquery 2.x, the datepicker feature started to work.

Answer (score 13):

I found that by commenting out the "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")" towards the bottom of _Layout.cshtml, I was able to resolve my issue with this.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for your help I spent hours trying to fix this.

Comment: This solved my issue as well! (of course several years later)

Comment: Still relevant to my challenge today. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked you haven't referenced JQuery twice? I found I'd included it in my layout and in my view. Removing one reference solved the problem.

Comment: I found this too. And the 2nd one was different than the first. Removing the 2nd fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

or this :

```
     <script" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
```

Instead of this :

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when upgrading to jQuery 2. I was caught out by the change in folder structure within the jQuery download; the jquery-ui.js file was no longer located in a ui folder and therefore my script tag was incorrectly mapped.

So in short, double check your references are correct!